# (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jackson

Parsing time error when there trying to create a list with attribute(IDValue=D005640) and without attribute element-based XML data. For 'IDValue' parsing I'm using JacksonXmlProperty annotation. I think this problem related to any unknown annotation or ObjectMapper related. Please anybody help.

Error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.*.model.dowjones.IDValue` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('D/005072')
```

XML element:

```
<ID IDType="Passport No.">
    <IDValue>D/005072</IDValue>
    <IDValue IDnotes="ECOWAS-DPL Passport (valid 07-Aug-2008 to 06-Jul-2010)">D-00172</IDValue>
    <IDValue IDnotes="Liberian Passport No">D005640</IDValue>
    <IDValue IDnotes="Liberian Passport No; Diplomatic">DD005640</IDValue>
    <IDValue IDnotes="Liberia">OR/0056672-01</IDValue>
</ID>



public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    JacksonXmlModule xmlModule = new JacksonXmlModule();
    xmlModule.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper(xmlModule);
    objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
    return objectMapper;
}


public <T> Object getObject(String filePath, T obj) {
    try {
        String xml = getString(filePath);
        return ObjectInstance.getObjectMapper().readValue(xml, obj.getClass());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        DowjonesApplication.logger.error("Xml to object construction fail!", e);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

BaseModel.java

```
@Data
@JsonSerialize
@JsonDeserialize
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BaseModel implements Serializable {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = -5616176897013108345L;
}
```

ID.java

```
@Data
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "ID")
public class ID extends BaseModel {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String IDType;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "IDValue")
    private List<IDValue> idValueList;
}
```

Error Details:

```
12-04-2021 18:06:49 |ERROR||[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1]|DEMO - line = 26: Xml to object construction fail!
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.*.model.dowjones.IDValue` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('D/005072')
        at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 551832] (through reference chain: com.example.*.model.PFA["Records"]->com.example.*.model.dowjones.Records["Person"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.*.model.dowjones.Person["IDNumberTypes"]->com.example.*.model.dowjones.IDNumberTypes["ID"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.*.model.dowjones.ID["IDValue"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1429)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1059)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdValueInstantiator.createFromString(StdValueInstantiator.java:323)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1373)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:171)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:161)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.WrapperHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(WrapperHandlingDeserializer.java:114)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.WrapperHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(WrapperHandlingDeserializer.java:114)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.WrapperHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(WrapperHandlingDeserializer.java:114)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:286)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:245)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:27)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.deser.WrapperHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(WrapperHandlingDeserializer.java:114)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4202)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3205)
        at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3173)
```